# Caching data with retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, caching, retrofit2

I am trying to access my data in offline mode also using retrofit, but it's not happening.
There is nothing wrong with the code but its not working.

log data for both WiFi status is same.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient
                .Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request request = chain.request();
                        if (isNetworkAvailable(context,ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)) {
                            request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 60).build();
                            Log.d("data",request.toString());
                        } else {
                            request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7).build();
                            Log.d("data1",request.toString());

                        }
                        return chain.proceed(request);
                    }
                })
                .cache(new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, 10 * 1024 * 1024)) // 10 MB
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient()
            .newBuilder()
            .cache(new Cache(getyourapplicationcontext.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 *1024))
            .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                Request request = chain.request();
                if (NetworkUtil.isDeviceConnectedToInternet(getyourapplicationcontext)) {
                    request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 60).build();
                } else {
                    request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7).build();
                }
                return chain.proceed(request);
            })
            .build();``
```